# Kotlin - clean loops/indexing

Tags: loops, kotlin

I have been writing code like:

```
index = 0 
while (index < 10){
    // do something
    index ++
}
```

I'd like to make this much cleaner, with something along the lines of

```
while(var index = 0; index < 10; index ++)
{
        // do something
        index ++
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate a [range](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) with e.g. `until` or `..`, and iterate over it with `for`:

```
for (index in 0 until 10) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
for (index in 0..9) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What your thinking of is analogous to a classical `for` loop such as in Java, C, etc.

In Kotlin this can be achieved by using [ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

```
for (i in 1..10) { // equivalent of 1 <= i && i <= 10
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: Is it really "if"?